# What is the state of BreezeJS integration with express and mongo DB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, breeze

I have forked BreezeJS and I have the EpressDemo running, the server is working and is connecting to Mongo. Though the DB is empty ( if anyone could tell me how to setup the initial data... ) the Metadata is set and Breeze is accessing it from the client. Now I understand that breeze is capable of keeping track of all the changes on the client but can I save them back to Mongo DB ? is there a Lib to install in the express app to save the dataBundle to mongodb ? or do I need to create my own method to save the data back ?

Answer (score 3):

Available now: please see the: [Breeze Mongo documentation](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/mongodb) and the [Zza sample](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/zza)

Answer (score 2):

Brett - you're jumping the gun a bit. The Mongo stuff isn't public yet ... not even alpha. It's checked-in ... well, we should have a specific development branch for it but we're not that big yet so we've tucked it in with everything else. We WILL let you know when we're ready to have you look.

## Update Aug 3, 2013

The first (beta) release of Breeze MongoDB support is ready to try. It's part of v.1.4.0. It's [documented here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/mongodb) and there's a [sample application called Zza!](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/zza).

We welcome your thoughts.

#### Please post extended suggestions/corrections to [Breeze User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions)

Comment: I've tried to download the Zza! source, but the download link always brings me back to the samples page. The download link http://www.breezejs.com/samples/www.breezejs.com/sites/all/files/Zza-Node-Mongo.zip seems broken

Comment: Shoot!  I just fixed it. Sorry.

Comment: unfortunately the provided mongodb files crash the server on Linux Ubuntu 12.04.2, mongodb-10gen v2.4.5. I don't know if it wouldn't be a better idea to export the db content to json so that we can import it back. Cheers.

Comment: I did a mongodump and zipped it up. Please [**download from here**](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/files/zza.mongodump.20130805.zip) and tell us if that works for you. If it does, I may switch to recommending that approach. It has the virtue of being much smaller too. General [restore instructions are here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#bin.mongorestore)

Comment: Ward, thanks again. I've had to modify a few things to get the sample to run on Linux. Some files had to be renamed to respect the casing. For example, Index.html to index.html, content folder to Content. What's the recommended way to give such feedback ?

Comment: Wow ... really? An OS cares?  I can go back and re-case everything because Windows doesn't care.  Thanks, btw. I'm not trying to be snarky. I am grateful for the feedback. In fact, PLEASE send it to us. Maybe you can amend your question with some suggestions and then I can answer with what we've done about them.

Comment: Yes, pretty much everything works, except some weirdness on the About page spewing out a lot of non printable characters... trying to figure it out. You guys should really host a forum for such discussions. SO is not too fond of discussions here.

Comment: The About page? You're kidding. Here is the About page **in its entirety**: "<div><h2>About Zza!</h2></div>". It doesn't even have a controller. LOL! You can always blog your story. Will gladly refer :)

Comment: FWIW, I just uploaded a new zip with (a) all-lowercase-directories and index.html, (b) the mongodump, (c) About.html is smaller and in one line: "<h2>About Zza!</h2>"

Comment: Ward, no, I'm not kidding. The problem doesn't seem to be the about.html file itself, but more a problem in the Express routing. I guess I should try this on Windows, but I don't want to install Node there :-) Maybe there's something in my Linux setup screwing things up. I'll let you know if I find the cause. BTW, have you guys done any testing on a platform other than Windows ?

Comment: Not yet. Want to. Grateful that you're willing to take some arrows for us.  There is an unnecessary fallback route ... one that is there only for development: `app.use('/', express.static(appDir)); // then look in regular zza`. It shouldn't matter. Does it help to remove it?

Comment: i am getting error on localhost:3001/breeze/Breeze/Lookups? can you please help me why i am getting this type of error (failed to load the resources ) mongo db server up and running not sure why node server getting this issue..