# How can I use MongoLab Api with Breeze.js?

Tags: mongodb, angularjs, breeze, mlab

How do I connect MongoDB using MongoLab Api to Breeze.js with angular.js  Can anyone help with wiring up the setup. Has anyone tried this setup?

```
https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/my-db/collections/my-coll?apiKey=myAPIKey
```

Here's datacontext.js from breeze site. 
Here's the plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/upp7wB?p=preview

```
app.factory('datacontext',['$http','logger',  function($http, logger) {
  var log = logger.log;

  log("Creating datacontext");
  configureBreeze();

  var useLocalHost = false;
  var host=useLocalHost ? "http://localhost:63428" : "http://sampleservice.breezejs.com";
  var serviceName = host+"/api/todos";

  var manager = new breeze.EntityManager(serviceName);

  plunkerHelpers.isCorsCapable();
  var datacontext = {
    getAllTodos: getAllTodos,
    reset: reset
  };
  return datacontext;

  /***  supporting functions ***/  

  function getAllTodos() {
    var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Todos");    
    log("Getting Todos");
    return manager.executeQuery(query).then(success);

    function success(data) {
        log("Retrieved " + data.results.length);
        return data.results;
    }
  }

  function reset() {
    manager.clear(); 
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    $http.post(serviceName + '/reset')
     .then(resetSuccess, resetFail);
    return deferred.promise;

    function resetSuccess() {
      log("Database reset");
      deferred.resolve();
    }
    function resetFail() {
      log("Database reset failed");
      deferred.reject(new Error("Database reset failed"));
    }
  }

  function configureBreeze() {
    // configure to use the model library for Angular
    breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("modelLibrary", "backingStore", true);
    // configure to use camelCase
    breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
  }
}]);
```

source Files.
http://www.breezejs.com/samples/todo-angular

https://support.mongolab.com/entries/20433053-REST-API-for-MongoDB

Comment: Check out the Zza! sample that Taytay mentioned, it should answer your question properly.

Answer (score 2):

About a week after you posted your question, the Breeze folks posted a full MongoDB example using using MongoDB-specific client and server adapters that they wrote.

They've [updated their MongoDB documentation here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/mongodb)

The example app is [Zza!](http://www.breezejs.com/samples/zza)

Their server-side adapter is a Node package called [breeze-mongodb](https://npmjs.org/package/breeze-mongodb)

Their client-side adapter is Breeze.dataservice.mongo.js ([Available on GitHub](https://raw.github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/master/Breeze.Client/Scripts/IBlade/breeze.dataService.mongo.js))

If I understand what you're asking, I think that the above resources will be a better starting place than their generic adapters. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a preliminary google search, I found the docs for connecting to breezejs: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/mongodb

Under the section **Breeze/MongoDB - Server side processing** they detail the steps to connect.

Example:

```
var host = 'localhost';
var port = 27017;
var dbName = 'MyNorthwindDatabase';
```

When you sign up with MongoLab, you can log in on the web UI and create a database.  Click on the database and you will find your URI- it should look something like this:  mongodb://dbuser:dbpassword@HOST:PORT/dbName

You should be able to use these credentials to connect to Breeze.

Happy coding!

edit: you may want to check out this thread on SO: [angular + breeze + mongoLab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748401/angular-breeze-mongolab)